# DAX: Projected sum for all months greater than current month of current year

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a requirement to filter a sum of projected sales for all months >= current month of the current year and any subsequent years that we have project sales data for.

So for 2023 I'd need the sum of projected sales for only February (the current month) through December 2023 on.

My DAX below accomplishes this accurately for current year OR current month, but I can't seem to filter by both without the results including all prior years. Client wants to see past sales and projected sales in the same visual so I cannot just filter out the prior years.

`CURRENT SUM OF SALES = CALCULATE(SUM('Table'[Sales]), FILTER('DateTable', YEAR('DateTable'[Date]) >= YEAR(TODAY())))`

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let me answer your request on writing a DAX that filters all months >= current month of the current year; you should create your date as follow:
DATE(YEAR(NOW()),MONTH(NOW()),1)

> Then add it to your measure as follow:

```
CURRENT SUM OF SALES = CALCULATE(SUM('Table'[Sales]), FILTER('DateTable', 'DateTable'[Date] >= DATE(YEAR(NOW()),MONTH(NOW()),1)))
```

Second, regarding your concern about your client wanting to see past sales and projected sales in the same visual, you only have to create another measure that shows past sales.

> If I understand your table structure correctly, this month's sales value will be updated to the actual value when your ETL refreshes the data next month; if not, please let me know.

> > **If my assumption is valid, you can write Past Sales - measure as follows:**

```
Past Sales = CALCULATE(SUM('Table'[Sales]), FILTER('DateTable', 'DateTable'[Date] < DATE(YEAR(NOW()),MONTH(NOW()),1)))
```

> > Then, use both measures in a Line chart with the 'DateTable'[Date] column as the X-axis.

*I hope I helped in a way; if so, please mark this as an answer and vote for it :)*

Comment: Worked perfectly, thank you. I had tried the MONTH(NOW()),1))) clause but my filter may have been off. Cheers!